# WCF Service with SQL SERVER database published in https

Tags: c#, database, rest, iis, https

I need to publish my wcf service in https with iis. The problem is that if I do this, the WCF Service doesn't connect with the database in sql server. Can someone help me please?
It has to be done without ado.net entity data model

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to ping your db from the machine where you deployed you wcf. please tell me if ping works. Also make sure that your connection string is correct and points not to localhost.